# SSIS Execute SQL Task - Conditional execution within the SQL script itself, not a condition at the task level, using a variable from outside the task

Tags: ssis

I have a ForEachLoop where I'm getting filepaths in a directory. I'm assigning those filepaths to a variable.  The goal is to write a filepath to a SQL table, so I'm passing in the filepath variable into the SQL Task.

I only want to write the filepath to the SQL table if it doesn't exist already, to prevent duplicates.  To do this, I have the following script to check if the filepath exists.

[image]

The code below gives me the error:  "*No value given for one or more required parameters. Problems exist with the query...*"ect

If I remove the 'IF' statement, it works.

```
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT FilePath FROM myTable WHERE FilePath = (?))
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO myTable
                (FilePath)
            VALUES
                (?)
        END 
END
```

What am I missing?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is I had to add another occurrence of the parameter(pointed to the variable) in the SQL Task.  If I'm using the variable twice, I have to have it mapped as a parameter twice.